# Loginview Question

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

```
       <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
   <RoleGroups>
     <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Administrators, Moderators"> 
       <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" Width="156px" BorderStyle="Dashed">
           <asp:TableRow runat="server" Height="50px" Width="50px">
               <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="BAN" Width="70px" /></asp:TableCell>
               <asp:TableCell runat="server"><asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="UNBAN" /></asp:TableCell>
           </asp:TableRow>
       </asp:Table>
   </asp:RoleGroup>
```

What is missing? it tells me: " System.Web.UI.WebControls.RoleGroup" doesnt have  a public property called Table..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add in the `<ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>` in after the `<asp:RoleGroup>`, then have all your other controlls within this.

Answer (score 0):

The `<ContentTemplate>` node is what's missing according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.aspx)